# How to count how many times each bookmark in Chrome has been clicked?

Tags: google-chrome, bookmarks

I have tons of Bookmarks in Chrome and there are some I use a lot, some I use less and some I don't use at all. I tried to figure out how to see how often I use my bookmarks. At first I was sure this is common issue but this topic came out as quite silent. I already figured many ways to do it in a difficult manner (e.g. exporting browser history and cross comparing against bookmarks or piping every click though local proxy / local file which would count all my clicks for me). But this seems overkill since there must be more efficient way to achieve this? It would not matter if solution would work only from here on and we wouldn't consider any clicks in the past.